# How to set event for Google chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am using Google API to draw chart but I want to set event for each row of this table but I don't know how should I collect this element for example I wanna set event that whenever clicked in **Magnolia Room** `alert("Magnolia Room clicked");`
Google chart link:
[Google Timeline Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)
here is google javascript chart code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('example5.3');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            dataTable.addRows([
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Intermediate Perl',   new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Advanced Perl',       new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Applied Perl',        new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Google Charts',       new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Closure',             new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'App Engine',          new Date(0,0,0,21,30,0), new Date(0,0,1,0,30,0) ]]);

            var options = {
                timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
                backgroundColor: '#ffd'
            };

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
</script>
```

And My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="example5.3" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to set an event for them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "select" event handler to do this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        alert(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].bb, 0) + ' clicked');
    }
});
```

Please note that the selection info is currently bugged; the selection objects should have `row` and `column` properties, but those properties are obfuscated, so for now you have to access the row indices from the `bb` property.  The Timeline visualization sets the column index to `null` for all selections, so you don't need to worry about that one.