# Putting Html tag in Google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart and I want to put anchor tag of Magnolia Room instead of for example Magnolia Room alone is there any way to do that?
Google Chart Link
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline
Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('example5.3');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            dataTable.addRows([
                [ '<a>Magnolia Room</a>' ,  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,test,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Intermediate Perl',   new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Advanced Perl',       new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Applied Perl',        new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Google Charts',       new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Closure',             new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'App Engine',          new Date(0,0,0,21,30,0), new Date(0,0,1,0,30,0) ]]);

            var options = {
                timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
                backgroundColor: '#ffd'
            };

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
    </script>
```

I found code to set event for that  but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {
        var match = e.targetID.match(/vAxis#\d+#label#(\d+)/);
        if (match) {
            var rowIndex = parseInt(match[1]);
            var axisLabel = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
            alert(axisLabel);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't use HTML in the bar labels, but you can use the "select" event to do whatever you want when someone clicks the bar.

Comment: but how can I set event for that because it is just name how can I collect it?????

Comment: See the answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24840991/613559

Comment: I think my previous question answer, event was about item not row lable so we I can't use that event because it is work when ever I clicked in item not row lable so I should use another event I think it's not select any more is click??

Comment: Would you please help me I need just an event for row lable at least guide me well!!!!

Comment: Change the column index passed to the `getValue` method call: `dataTable.getValue(selection[0].bb, 0)` gets the data in column 0 (the row label), `dataTable.getValue(selection[0].bb, 1)` gets the data in column 1 (the bar label).  Is that what you are looking for, or do you need something else?

Comment: No its not this event work when I clicked on item not row label so if I change it to 0 it wont work either I want when ever I clicked in row label alert for example "row label clicked" that what I mean!!!